# JavaScript to Alternate Between 2 MS Charts Using Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 MS charts that I want to alternate between, depending on which radio button is selected. I'm having multiple issues with this. Using JavaScript, ASP.NET, and VB.

1) SOLVED: see below. Right now, the radio buttons will alternate between the two. However, the page loads showing both at the same time. Once I click on a radio button, the other one disappears, and it functions as it should. I want the page to load with only one chart.

2) The charts should "replace" one another, showing up where the other one was before. Right now, they're stacked vertically, and when I make the other one invisible, there's just a big batch of white space where it used to be.

Here's the relevant code.

Chart Component

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="HomeAutoContainer" runat="server">
            <div id="BindsAuto" runat="server">
                <asp:Chart ID="chTotalBindsAuto" runat="server" Height="230px" Width="280px">
                    <Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
            </div>
            <div id="BindsHome" runat="server">
                <asp:Chart ID="chTotalBindsHome" runat="server" Height="230px" Width="280px">
                    <Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top" align="center">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoBindsList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Auto" Text="Auto" Selected="True">Auto</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Home" Text="Home">Home</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Page Load of the component

```
rdoBindsList.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "BindsAutoHomeSwitch('" + rdoBindsList.Items(0).ToString + "','" + BindsAuto.ClientID + "','" + BindsHome.ClientID + "' );")
```

JavaScript function

```
function BindsAutoHomeSwitch(rdoAutoHomeID, chTotalBindsAuto1, chTotalBindsHome1) {
        var rdoAutoHome = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentArea_AutoTotalBinds1_rdoBindsList_0");
        var chTotalBindsHomeGraph = document.getElementById(chTotalBindsHome1);
        var chTotalBindsAutoGraph = document.getElementById(chTotalBindsAuto1);
        var selectedGraphValue
        if (rdoAutoHome.checked) {
            selectedGraphValue = "Auto"
        }
        else {
            selectedGraphValue = "Home"
        }


        if (selectedGraphValue == "Home") {
           chTotalBindsAutoGraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
           chTotalBindsHomeGraph.style.visibility = "visible";

        }
        if (selectedGraphValue == "Auto") {
            chTotalBindsAutoGraph.style.visibility = "visible";
            chTotalBindsHomeGraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of setting `visibility` set `display:none`. This will hide a div without it taking up space in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOADING SOLVED: Needed to add a JavaScript function and call it from the page load to hide it.

Page Load

```
rdoBindsList.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "BindsAutoHomeSwitch('" + rdoBindsList.Items(0).ToString + "','" + BindsAuto.ClientID + "','" + BindsHome.ClientID + "' );")
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "HideHome", "HideHomeGraphOnLoad('" + BindsHome.ClientID + "' );", True)
```

JS

```
function HideHomeGraphOnLoad(chTotalBindsHome1) {
        var chTotalBindsHomeGraph = document.getElementById(chTotalBindsHome1);
        chTotalBindsHomeGraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

CHART STACKING SOLVED: Needed to set up positioning on some DIVs in order to make it work.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="HomeAutoContainer" runat="server" style="position:relative; width:280px; height:230px">
            <div id="BindsAuto" runat="server" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <asp:Chart ID="chTotalBindsAuto" runat="server" Height="230px" Width="280px">
                    <Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
            </div>
            <div id="BindsHome" runat="server" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <asp:Chart ID="chTotalBindsHome" runat="server" Height="230px" Width="280px">
                    <Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;" align="center">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoBindsList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Auto" Text="Auto" Selected="True">Auto</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Home" Text="Home">Home</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
```